# Widget changes in customizer ajax error to many options?

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

Just testing frontend widget changes via customizer and I am not even able to change the title. Ajax response says

```
{"success":false,"data":"widget_setting_too_many_options"}
```

There is also a notice http://prntscr.com/kk518f  but there are no errors anywhere.

The notice comes from here https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/56c162fbc9867f923862f64f1b4570d885f1ff03/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php#L1471

and if I read that correctly it says to stop if count of captured options is bigger than 1 meaning that it somehow "sees" a duplicated option for the title.

I was not able to find any references to this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The customizer can not/will not track changes to more than one option. I am not sure why, but that is a definite design limitation. Most likely your widget code tries to update an option.

In general, regardless of customizer, you should not do that. All of a widget settings should be limited to its on storage in the relevant options. Any global setting should have a global admin interface to control it, like a dedicated admin window.

Comment: Thnx for the answer but I am not sure where I referenced that I am changing any widgets or have own widgets or own widgets options. I am simply changing existing WP widget title via customizer. Nothing else.

Comment: oh sorry, I got an impression this relates to your own widget. In that case you need to find the specific widget and ask the plugin developer to fix it